# Compare a row with previous 12 values

Tags: sql-server, sas

I am trying to compare a value with previous 12 months/12 rows. If the value is yes in last 12 months then yes for the 12th row. Likewise for each and every row (compare previous 12 values).

I am doing it in following way. Its working but I have to do it for multiple columns, so code is going to be very lengthy.

Is there any way we can do it in simple step for n number of columns?

```
select *,
--Identify customers who have applied for principal relief within the past 12 months
 lag(PrincipalReliefFlag,1)  over(partition by id,productcode order by snapshot_date) PRflg1
,lag(PrincipalReliefFlag,2)  over(partition by id,productcode order by snapshot_date) PRflg2
,lag(PrincipalReliefFlag,3)  over(partition by id,productcode order by snapshot_date) PRflg3
,lag(PrincipalReliefFlag,4)  over(partition by id,productcode order by snapshot_date) PRflg4
,lag(PrincipalReliefFlag,5)  over(partition by id,productcode order by snapshot_date) PRflg5
,lag(PrincipalReliefFlag,6)  over(partition by id,productcode order by snapshot_date) PRflg6
,lag(PrincipalReliefFlag,7)  over(partition by id,productcode order by snapshot_date) PRflg7
,lag(PrincipalReliefFlag,8)  over(partition by id,productcode order by snapshot_date) PRflg8
,lag(PrincipalReliefFlag,9)  over(partition by id,productcode order by snapshot_date) PRflg9
,lag(PrincipalReliefFlag,10) over(partition by id,productcode order by snapshot_date) PRflg10
,lag(PrincipalReliefFlag,11) over(partition by id,productcode order by snapshot_date) PRflg11
into #test
from #temp

select *
,case when (PrincipalReliefFlag='Y' or PRflg1='Y' or PRflg2='Y' or PRflg3='Y' or PRflg4='Y' or PRflg5='Y' or PRflg6='Y' or PRflg7='Y' or PRflg8='Y' or PRflg9='Y' or PRflg10='Y' or  PRflg11='Y')
    then  'Y' 
    when (PrincipalReliefFlag='N' 
                                and (PRflg1='N' or PRflg1 is null)  
                                and (PRflg2='N' or PRflg2 is null) 
                                and (PRflg3='N' or PRflg3 is null) 
                                and (PRflg4='N'  or PRflg4 is null)
                                and (PRflg5='N' or PRflg5 is null)
                                and (PRflg6='N' or  PRflg6 is null)
                                and (PRflg7='N' or PRflg7 is null)
                                and (PRflg8='N' or  PRflg8  is null)
                                and (PRflg9='N' or PRflg9 is null)
                                and (PRflg10='N' or PRflg10 is null)
                                and (PRflg11='N' or PRflg11 is null) )
    then 'N'
    end PrincipalRelief_applied_in_last12m
from #test
```

Expecting simple step. tried using joins as well but could not make it.

Comment: why is MySQL tagged as this is not valid MySQL code, this seams to relating to SQL Server (MSSQL)/Sybase.. As the `#` is valid syntax in those RDMS..

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: i wonder if `snapshot_date` is always unique in a *"`id,productcode'"* group or if ties are possible..  Like @GordonLinoff  already said a example would be very usefull .. See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select t.*,
       max(PrincipalReliefFlag) over (partition by id, productcode
                                      order by snapshot_date
                                      rows between 11 preceding and current row
                                     ) as PrincipalReliefFlag_12
from #temp t;
```

This takes the maximum value over the 12-month period -- and will work if the flag takes on only the values of `'Y'` and `'N'`.

Comment: quick question, how does max function work on character value?

Comment: Ramu, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18558620/sql-max-function-in-non-numeric-columns)'s a great writeup on that question.

Comment: *"quick question, how does max function work on character value? "* @Ramu you know that character sets are basically nothing more then (pre)defined hexdecimals/binairy sets from a software side of view? Internally `MAX()/MIN()` should use a to hex or to binairy conversion when used on characters

Comment: Thank you Raymond